# jquery mousenter headache.

Tags: jquery, fadeout, mouseenter

I have a problem with mouse enter and mouse leave and fadeout. The code works ok if you move your mouse slowly. If you hover over the elements quickly it stays at the wrong state. I have the impression that it needs a callback to confirm the completion of the fadeout. But I am not sure how to do that. here is a fiddle 
  http://jsfiddle.net/alexnode/6s7Jg/1/

```
$('#button1r').mouseenter(function () {
    $('#button1r').fadeOut("300");
});
$('#button1').mouseout(function () {
    $('#button1r').fadeIn("300");
});
$('#button2r').mouseenter(function () {
    $('#button2r').fadeOut("300");
});
$('#button2').mouseout(function () {
    $('#button2r').fadeIn("300");
});
$('#button3r').mouseenter(function () {
    $('#button3r').fadeOut("300");
});
$('#button3').mouseout(function () {
    $('#button3r').fadeIn("300");
});
$('#button4r').mouseenter(function () {
    $('#button4r').fadeOut("300");
});
$('#button4').mouseout(function () {
    $('#button4r').fadeIn("300");
});

<img id="button1" class="button" data-case="translation" src="http://www.translationgames.org/images/button1overlay.png" alt="Translation games">
<img id="button1r" class="button" data-case="translation" src="http://www.translationgames.org/images/button1.png" alt="Translation games">
<img id="button2" class="button" data-case="art" src="http://www.translationgames.org/images/button2overlay.png" alt="Translation games">
<img id="button2r" class="button" data-case="art" src="http://www.translationgames.org/images/button2.png" alt="Translation games">
```

I tried hover and it created another problem, show I tried to break it down to mouseenter.

Comment: When you call fadeOut on the same element that you bound the mouse enter / mouse leave to, then it will automatically call the mouseout as soon as the fadeout is finished. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: What about using class???

Comment: the idea is that each one will behave a bit differently. I have doing the same at the moment trying to figure out what is wrong

Comment: I meant I am using the same code for each mouse over at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use [stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to end the current animation before beginning a new animation. You can also simplify your handlers like so:

```
$('#button1r, #button2r, #button3r, #button4r').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).stop().fadeOut("300");
});

$('#button1, #button2, #button3, #button4').mouseout(function () {
    $('#' + this.id + 'r').stop().fadeIn("300");
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much still if your run your mouse really quickly there are a few buttons remaining active.

Comment: I just show the solution with the fail !!! that works ! it is brilliant. Why did you delete it ? I want to mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Ah... it turns out it wasn't quite working correctly... I forgot to wrap the fail function in a `function() {...}` so it was executing immediately when beginning the animation. If you look closely, the fade out animation was gone

Comment: I see, still i will use it though! At least it looks consistent and it has the end animation. I tried to do my self a callback with promise() or done() but I am a rookie and didn't manage to make it work properly. I just stopped it. Is that a small bug or there is a completely different way of doing it ?

Answer (score 1):

It's because the mouseenter and mouseout are not working on same element, you should do something like this:

```
$('#button1r').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).fadeOut("300");
}).mouseout(function () {
    $(this).fadeIn("300");
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6s7Jg/2/)

Comment: This is working but creates another problem that when the mouse stays on the button it blinks. it repeats the animation all the time. I will play a bit more with it. maybe mousein will work.

Comment: i tried mouse over but it doesn't make any difference. i also tried to use it with stop but doesn't work

Comment: You see what is the problem in your fiddle the last three buttons that seem working properly they actually don't. If you move your mouse quickly one or two of them remain active. And the top one is blinking when the cursor is over.

Answer (score 0):

you should do a "stop()" so the previous animation doens't interfere with the current one.

about the callback it's very easy to use:

```
$('#button4r').mouseenter(function () {
    $('#button4r').fadeOut("300", function fadedOut(){
        alert("#button4r fadedOut")
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried this method and still has the animation remaing active if you move really quickly.

Comment: this shows some promise i guess if i use that with a boolean i can have more control on when it plays. I am working a bit on that now.